# Unable to execute ExtJs library 4 code in linux CentOs

Tags: php, extjs

I have a project running on PHP, ExtJs Library 4 which runs perfectly fine on production server, i am trying to run the same code in my local environment (Centos - is a new server with nothing installed related to extJS) which is giving issue and not able to execute app.js file though the index page appears.

The application is hosted currently and i am trying to create a local environment for the same. So i have downloaded the code and tried running the same on the local system which is having php installed. When i hit the URL the index page loads properly. There is an app.js which is called the first time i hit the login button.

On login i am trying with the code as below:-

```
onLogin: function (a, d, c) {
        var b = this;
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: ACTYLA.Settings.loginUrl,
            params: {
                userName: c.userName,
                password: c.password
            },
            success: function (e) {
                var g = Ext.decode(e.responseText);
                if (g != "false") {
                    a.destroy();
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Login Successful", "Welcome " + g[0].userName);
                    b.initializeApp(g)
                } else {
                    d.getForm().reset();
                    b.getLblMessage().show()
                }
            },
            failure: function () {
                Ext.Msg.alert("Invalid Response", "You entered invalid credentials.", function () {
                    d.getForm().reset()
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

I have tried debugging with logs in my controller but there it for sure is not reaching till the controller file. All i get in response is the index.html content.

please note i have not installed anything related to ext JS. What all is needed to be installed or downloaded to make this application work?

Comment: You absolutely need to share more context. What does "giving issue" mean? Why are you "not able" to execute something? Are there any error messages given?

Comment: @NicoHaase Trying to login and making a Ajax Request using Ext.Ajax.request which is returning the same html in response and does not reach the controller.

Comment: Please add all information to the question itself, not to the comment section. What does "does not reach the controller" mean? What have you tried to find the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase added all info in question

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to download ExtJs library ([ext-4.2.1](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/ext-4.2.1-gpl.zip)).
2. Then create folder under your webservers public folder and extract downloaded library there (check by accessing https://yourserveraddress/createdfolder/ext-all.js).
3. Now open your index.html for editing and look for a line with "ext-all *** .js", like:

   < script type="text/javascript" src="https://myserver.home/extjs-4.2.1/ext-all-debug.js">
4. Change the src part to the address you got in point 2. If there is many such lines, you have to change/update them all.
5. Start the application ("hit the URL").

PS. That was for setting up ExtJs. You seem to have running webserver, you also mentioned about php. As your code includes login system, you might need to install/setup database too.